# loginCtrl is not correct hence unable to use auth0 with ionic

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, auth0

I am trying to develop an ionic app using `auth0 authentication` and I followed [these instructions](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic). Once I add the `loginCtrl` it returns an error.

**Error**

> [ng:areq] Argument 'loginCtrl>' is not a function got undefined or TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseOptions' of undefined

**Controller.js File**

```
angular.module('comicsApp')
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })
    .controller('contactsController', function(contfact, $scope, $ionicLoading) {
        var _this = this;

        $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
            $ionicLoading.show();


            contfact.getContacts().then(function(response){
                _this.contactitem = response.data;


            }).catch(function(response){
                //request was not successful
                //handle the error
            }).finally(function(){
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            });
        });
    })
      .controller('iPController',function ($scope,$http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:9510/api/profiles/Getprofile")
                .success(function(response) {$scope.ipInfo = response;})
                .error(function(response) {
                    $scope.message="Error";
                })
    })

          .controller('contactdtl-Controller',function ($scope,$http,$stateParams) {


        $http.get("http://localhost:9510/api/contacts/usercontacts/",{params: { "id": $stateParams.id }
                })
                .success(function(response) {$scope.contactdtlinfo = response;})
                .error(function(response) {
                    $scope.message="Error";
                })
    })


       .controller('addcontact',function ($scope,$http,$stateParams) {


          $scope.save = function () {

        if (this.lastname != "123") {



            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               // data: JSON.stringify(this.contact),
                url: 'http://localhost:9510/api/contacts/Postcontacts',
                data: ({"owner":this.owner,"fisrtname":this.fisrtname,"lastname":this.lastname,"mobile":this.mobile,"email":this.email,"relation":this.relation,"home":this.home,"office":this.home})
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
               // $scope.productsData.push(response.data);
               // $scope.clear();
                alert("Product Added Successfully !!!");
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionMessage);
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
        }
    };
})



        .controller('heartattack',function ($scope,$http, $ionicPopup,$state,$ionicPlatform, $cordovaGeolocation) {

 $scope.showConfirm = function($scope) {

  /////////////////////////////////////////get coordinates //////////////////////////////////////////

  ///////////////////////////////////////get coordinates /////////////////////////////////////////////
   var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
     title: 'Confirm Heartattack',
     template: 'ARE YOU SURE THAT YOU WANT TO RECORED YOUR CASE ?'
   });

   confirmPopup.then(function(res,$scope) {
     if(res) {







        $scope.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
          $scope.time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');


            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               // data: JSON.stringify(this.contact),
                url: 'http://localhost:9510/api/reports/Postreport',
                data: ({
    "id": 1,
    "type": "heartattack",
    "coordinates": '$essam',
    "location": "adfasdfas",
    "injuries": 1,
    "time": $scope.time,
    "date":  $scope.date,
    "details": "having heart attack",   
    "owner": 232
  })
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
               // $scope.productsData.push(response.data);
               // $scope.clear();

               // alert("Product Added Successfully !!!");
               $state.go('heartattack');

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionMessage);
            });
     } else {



     }
   });
 };


   })




       .controller('addreport',function ($scope,$http,$stateParams) {


          $scope.save = function () {


          $scope.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
          $scope.time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
            $scope.test=this.type;
            alert($scope.test);

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               // data: JSON.stringify(this.contact),
                url: 'http://localhost:9510/api/reports/Postreport',
                data: ({

                  "id": 1,
                  "type": this.type,
                  "coordinates": "asasdfasddfasdf",
                  "location": this.location,
                  "injuries": this.injuries,
                  "time":  $scope.time ,
                  "date":  $scope.date,
                  "details": this.details,
                  "owner": 232

                })
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
               // $scope.productsData.push(response.data);
               // $scope.clear();
                alert("Report Added Successfully !!!");
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionMessage);
            });

    };
})


   .controller('LoginController',function LoginController ($scope, $state, auth, store){

    var vm = this;

    function doLogin() {
      auth.signin({
        container: 'lock-container',
        authParams: {
          scope: 'openid offline_access',
          device: 'Mobile device'
        }
      }, function (profile, token, accessToken, state, refreshToken) {
        // Success callback
        store.set('profile', profile);
        store.set('token', token);
        store.set('accessToken', accessToken);
        store.set('refreshToken', refreshToken);

         $state.go("home");
      }, function () {
        // Error callback
      });
    }

    doLogin();

});


.controller('watchme',function ($scope,$timeout,$cordovaFlashlight,$cordovaSms,$ionicPlatform) {

  $scope.myTimer={};
 $scope.myTimer.value=5;

   $scope.myTimerFixed=5;
   $scope.myTimer.startBtn=false;
   $scope.myTimer.stopBtn=true;

  var svg=document.getElementsByClassName('round-progress')[0];
  svg.onload=function()  {

    $scope.radius=svg.getBoundingClientRect().width/2;
  }
  var myTimerVariable;
  $scope.myCustomtTime = function() {


    $scope.myTimer.value--;
    if($scope.myTimer.value==0){

      $timeout.cancel(myTimerVariable);
      complete(false);


      return false;
    }

    myTimerVariable=$timeout($scope.myCustomtTime, 1000);
  }
$scope.start=function(){

$scope.myTimer.startBtn=true;
   $scope.myTimer.stopBtn=false;

  myTimerVariable=$timeout($scope.myCustomtTime, 1000);



};






$scope.stop=function(){

 complete(true);
 $timeout.cancel(myTimerVariable);

};
var complete=  function(forceFullAbort){

  if(forceFullAbort){

    alert('you killed the timer');
    $cordovaFlashlight.switchOff()
    .then(
      function (success) { /* success */ },
      function (error) { /* error */ });

  }
  else
  {

    alert('time completed');
 // $cordovaFlashlight.switchOn()
 //    .then(
 //      function (success) { /* success */ },
 //      function (error) { /* error */ });

    //  $cordovaSms.send('66549815', 'help me').then(function(){
    //   alert("SMS enviado com sucesso");
    // }, function(err){
    //   alert('Erro ao enviar SMS');
    // });

      var number = 66549815;
           var onSuccess=function(number){

               alert("invia messaggio");
           };

           function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }

           window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(onSuccess, onError, number);


  }





  $scope.myTimer.startBtn=false;
   $scope.myTimer.stopBtn=true;
};
$scope.getStyle = function(){
                var transform = ($scope.isSemi ? '' : 'translateY(-50%) ') + 'translateX(-50%)';

                return {
                    'top':'50%',
                    'bottom':  'auto',
                    'left': '50%',
                    'transform': transform,
                    '-moz-transform': transform,
                    '-webkit-transform': transform,
                    'font-size': $scope.radius/3.5 + 'px'
                };
            };

  })

        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be completely off the ball here but looking at your code I cannot see a "loginCtrl" but a "logincontroller". Is this a typo on your question or is your html trying to call loginCtrl ?